# winexe execute command on windows with pipe and quotes

Tags: bash, winexe, dsquery

```
1- dsquery user -disabled | dsget user -display -email -dept -title
2- dsquery computer  -limit 1000 | sort
3- dsquery user "dc=YOURDOMAINNAME" -inactive 2 | dsget user -display -email -dept -title'
```

Using WINEXE on Linux, I am trying to execute above commands on remote windows 2008 but getting error.

```
winexe -U DOMAIN/ADMIN%"PASSWORD" //10.0.0.1 "dsquery user -disabled | dsget user -display -email -dept -title"

ERROR
dsquery failed:'dsget' is an unknown parameter.
type dsquery /? for help.root@linux:/temp#

 winexe -U DOMAIN/ADMIN%"PASSWORD" //10.0.0.1 "dsquery user "dc=MYDOMAIN" -inactive 2 | dsget user -display -email -dept -title'"

dsquery failed:'|' is an unknown parameter.
```

Comment: I'm missing the context the question has with programming

Comment: wrap the remote command in a `cmd.exe /c` invocation

Comment: @GrishaLevit
cmd /c 
It worked !
Thanks
One Eaxmple:
winexe -U DOMAIN/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.0 "cmd /c net user USERNAME /domain"